# Continuous random variable and its cdf

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable. Is $F_X$ (it's cdf) **strictly** increasing (almost everywhere)? I think an equivalent question is is $f_X>0$ almost everywhere?

**Edit:** The answer as in @Did comment is no, the cdf does not need to be strictly increasing and a counterexample is $X=U+2B$ where $U$ and $B$ are independent and $U$ is uniform$(0,1)$ and $B$ is $1$ with probability $1/2$ and $0$ with probability $1/2$. Proof is in the comments below.

Comment: No. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Is there an intuitive reason why not? Would a counterexample require some "weird" function like the Cantor function?

Comment: Nothing weird. Try X=U+2B where U is uniform on the interval (0,1) and B is Bernoulli 0 or 1, independent of U.

Comment: Thanks. Just to confirm
$$
Pr(X<x)=Pr(U+2B\leq x)=\frac{1}{2}[Pr(U<x)+Pr(U<x-2)]
=
\left\{\begin{array}{cc}0 & x\leq 0 \\
      \frac{x}{2} & 0\leq x\leq 1 \\
      \frac{1}{2} & 1\leq x\leq 2 \\
      \frac{1}{2}(x-1) & 2\leq x\leq 3 \\
      1 & 3\leq x  \end{array} \right.
$$ If you want to write this solution, I'll give you the points.